# Watermark on every loaded images in a specific path

Tags: php, watermark

I need to add watermarks (yeah... ugly I know) to all images the user adds to the text. I came across the htaccess method that adds the mark to the images without destroying the original image. I like that idea, but the problem with ia it hits all the images... including my background and styling elements of the website. Could not get it to work only in images from a specific subfolder.

I have a string called: computertext, which containt the content the user enters. Text and sometimes img links to images in the userfiles/image/folder.

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('imagetobemarked.jpg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$newimage = imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);</i>
```

My problem is that it doesn't create a new image to be replace in $computertext. It just echo's the new image and completely overrules my website. When I kill 'header('Content-type: image/jpeg');' it does show my website, but also shows the image in code.

I want to create a temp. new image file to be replaced in $computertext. But can't get it to simple create a new string-image.

Please help :) thx very much for you time!
Christian

Comment: Add a tag that says what language you're using. Otherwise, you're probably not gonna get help.

Answer (score 1):

Found it out myself.
Put the png, php and a new htaccess-file in de subfolder.

Put this in the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jp?g|png))$ /subfolderpath/watermark.php?image=$1&watermark=watermark.png [NC]
```

Comment: How receive the PHP the "image"? Do you made a REQUEST['image'] ?